# Creating a custom ESLint rule for TypeScript Interface

Tags: eslint

[Documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/custom-rules#scope-types) with more context.

Objective: Create a custom ESLint rule to block inclusion of release tags (`@alpha`, `@beta`, `@internal`) inside the parent (`class`, `function`, `interface`, `type`)

ESLint several scope types when traversing through the AST nodes, and I can cover `class` and `function` using the `ClassDeclaration` / `ClassExpression` and `FunctionDeclaration` / `FunctionExpression`.

However, the only way that I could figure out for the `interface` was to use the `Program` type with global scope. Is there a way to access the node with `interface` type to create custom ESLint rule?

I created multiple test suites for ClassExpression, ClassDeclaration and Interface types. The custom ESLint rule that I created has a `create(context)` method as below. The problem is that the class will not only return ClassDeclaration, but also a Program object from the test suite.

`create(context) { return { ClassDeclaration(node) { classErrorLoggerHelper(node, context) }, ClassExpression(node) { classExpressionErrorLoggerHelper(node, context) }, Program(node) { programErrorLoggerHelper(node, context) } }; },`